# Произведение чисел, заданных одномерным массивом

Tags: java, массивы

Возвращает произведение чисел, заданных одномерным массивом array. Для пустого одномерного массива возвращает 0. хоть убей не понимаю что не так.

```
public int mul(int[] array) {
        int x = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            x *= array[i];
        }
        if (x==0){
            return 0;
        }  else {
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не правда, для пустого массива возвращает 1. Я проверил. И ваш код излишне многословен, достаточно return x;

Comment: "что не так" - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это очень сложный код, я бы сделал так:

```
public static int mul(int... array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).reduce(1, Math::multiplyExact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

сам нашел ответ.

```
public int mul(int[] array) {
        int x = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            x *= array[i];
        }
        if (array.length==0){
            return 0;
        }  else {
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Код в вопросе не возвращал ноль для пустого, этот возвращает. "Они сами не знают, чего хочут"?

Comment: @MBo, а если кроме кода в вопросе прочитать сам вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я увидел, что автора возмущает
`Для пустого одномерного массива возвращает 0. хоть убей не понимаю что не так`, хотя код такого не даёт.

Comment: @MBo, так он имел в виду "должно возвращать 0", но не работает. А тут исправил и теперь действительно возвращает 0.

Comment: Угу, он мог написать "не возвращает" или "должен возвращать", но написано-то другое. Поэтому и цитата В.Невинного